# mips single-cycle branch verilog

Tags: verilog, computer-architecture, hardware, mips

I'm fairly new to Verilog, hardware design and computer architecture. Nevertheless, I've had a go at designing a simplified MIPS processor. It seems to mostly work fine but whenever I simulate it, it hangs on a BEQ instruction.

I'm trying to get it to run the following program (R1 is preloaded with 32'd10 and R4 is preloaded with 32'd1):

```
0    ADD R0 R1 R5; // R1 = 10
4    ADD R0 R1 R5; // R5 = 10 (redundant)
8    ADD R5 R6 R6; // R6 = R5 + R6
C    SUB R5 R4 R5; // R5 = R5 - 1
10   SLT R4 R5 R7; // R4 < R5
14   BEQ R7 R4 -3; // Loop back to 8 if R5 > 1
```

Here is the GTKWave output:

[image]

As I understand it, the low 16 bits of the instruction should go to sign_extend, where it is concatenated with 16 copies of the sign bit. This then goes to shift_left2, where the address is multiplied by 4. This is added to the previous address + 4.

The two operands sent to the ALU are equal so the z0 signal is asserted. The Branch signal is asserted by the control module, based on bits [31:26] of the instruction. Branch and zero are ANDed in branch_and, causing branchnd to be asserted. This is fed into a mux to select the branch address instead of the incremented previous address and fed back in to the program counter, assigned to next_address on the next clock cycle, and fed into the instruction memory to fetch the next address.

It looks like all of this happens in my simulation. The branched address can be seen on addin at 12 seconds in the above picture, so it appears to function correctly up to that point. I can't understand why it hangs though. Surely this should just be fed into the program counter, assigned to next_address on the next posedge of the clock, and used to fetch the instruction. If I change the program so that the branch isn't taken, then it continues to execute until it runs out of instructions, so it does seem to be related to taking the branch.

I've tried changing sensitivity lists, adding/removing the clock from modules and just about anything else I can think of. Maybe I am missing something obvious. I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone could help. I'm new here so if this isn't the correct way to go about asking a question or if there is anything I can do to make this question easier to answer, please let me know.

Thanks

```
module MIPS_tb();

wire [4:0] rs1, rt1, rd1, writereg1;
wire [31:0] ins, register0, register1, register4, register5, register6, register7, addin, aluout, nextadd,
        op1, op2, rfoutput2, dmreaddata, se_address, wdata, braddr, shaddr, incPCaddr;
wire reg_write, branch, branchnd, z0, regds, memtoreg, memwrite, alusrc;
reg clock;
reg reset;


MIPS mips1(clock, reset, rs1, rt1, rd1, writereg1, reg_write, ins,
     register1, register4, register5, register6, register7, branch, branchnd, z0, addin, aluout, nextadd,
    op1, op2, rfoutput2, dmreaddata, se_address, wdata, braddr, shaddr, incPCaddr, regds, memtoreg, memwrite, alusrc);

initial
begin
    $dumpfile("MIPS_MIPS_tb.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, clock, reset, rs1, rt1, rd1, writereg1, reg_write, ins,
     register1, register4, register5, register6, register7, branch, branchnd, z0, addin, aluout, nextadd,
    op1, op2, rfoutput2, dmreaddata, se_address, wdata, braddr, shaddr, incPCaddr, regds, memtoreg, memwrite, alusrc);
    reset = 1'b1;
    clock = 1'b0;
#1
    reset = 1'b0;

    repeat(250)
#1      
        clock = !clock;
#1
    $finish;
end


endmodule
```

MIPS

```
module MIPS(clock, reset, rs1, rt1, rd1, writereg1, reg_write, ins,
     register1, register4, register5, register6, register7, branch, branchnd, z0, addin, aluout, nextadd,
    op1, op2, rfoutput2, dmreaddata, se_address, wdata, braddr, shaddr, incPCaddr, regds, memtoreg, memwrite, alusrc);

input clock, reset;


output [4:0] rs1, rt1, rd1, writereg1;
output [31:0] ins, addin, aluout;
output reg_write;
output [31:0] register1, register4, register5, register6, register7, nextadd, op1, op2,
        rfoutput2, dmreaddata, se_address, wdata, braddr, shaddr, incPCaddr;
output branch, branchnd, z0, regds, memtoreg, memwrite, alusrc;


wire [31:0] instruction, next_address, address_in, operand1, operand2, reg_file_output2, 
        ALU_result, data_mem_read_data, sign_extended_address, write_data,
        branch_address, shifted_address, incremented_PC_address;
wire RegDst, Branch, MemtoReg, MemWrite, ALUSrc, RegWrite, zero, BEQ;
wire [1:0] ALUOp;
wire [4:0] rs, rt, rd, write_register;
wire [5:0] funct;
wire [15:0] addressop;
wire [3:0] ALU_control_vector;

assign rs1 = rs;
assign rt1 = rt;
assign rd1 = rd;
assign writereg1 = write_register;
assign reg_write = RegWrite;
assign ins = instruction;
assign z0 = zero;
assign branch = Branch;
assign branchnd = BEQ;
assign addin = address_in;
assign aluout = ALU_result;
assign nextadd = next_address;

assign op1 = operand1;
assign op2 = operand2;
assign rfoutput2 = reg_file_output2;
assign dmreaddata = data_mem_read_data;
assign se_address = sign_extended_address;
assign wdata = write_data;
assign braddr = branch_address;
assign shaddr = shifted_address;
assign incPCaddr = incremented_PC_address;
assign regds = RegDst;
assign memtoreg = MemtoReg;
assign memwrite = MemWrite;
assign alusrc = ALUSrc; 


program_counter     pc1(next_address, address_in, clock, reset);

register_file   rf1(operand1, reg_file_output2, rs, rt, write_register, write_data, RegWrite,
             register1, register4, register5, register6, register7);

ALU alu1(ALU_result, zero, operand1, operand2, ALU_control_vector);

ALU_control aluctrl1(ALU_control_vector, ALUOp, funct);

data_memory dm1(data_mem_read_data, reg_file_output2, ALU_result, MemWrite);

sign_extend se1(sign_extended_address, addressop);

instruction_memory  im1(instruction, next_address);

control     ctrl1(RegDst, Branch, MemtoReg, ALUOp, MemWrite, ALUSrc, RegWrite, instruction,
            rs, rt, rd, funct, addressop);  

branch_adder    ba1(branch_address, shifted_address, incremented_PC_address);

PC_increment    pci(incremented_PC_address, next_address);

branch_and  brand(BEQ, Branch, zero);

shift_left2 shl2(shifted_address, sign_extended_address);

mux_2to1    branch_mux(address_in, BEQ, incremented_PC_address, branch_address);

mux_2to1_5bit   write_reg_mux(write_register, RegDst, rt, rd);

mux_2to1    write_data_mux(write_data, MemtoReg, ALU_result, data_mem_read_data);

mux_2to1    ALU_source_mux(operand2, ALUSrc, reg_file_output2, sign_extended_address);

endmodule
```

Control Unit

```
module control(RegDst, Branch, MemtoReg, ALUOp, MemWrite, ALUSrc, RegWrite, instruction,
    rs, rt, rd, funct, addressop);  

output RegDst, Branch, MemtoReg, MemWrite, ALUSrc, RegWrite;
output [4:0] rs, rt, rd;
output [5:0] funct;
output [15:0] addressop;
output [1:0] ALUOp;
input [31:0] instruction;

wire [5:0] Op = instruction[31:26];

assign rs = instruction[25:21];
assign rt = instruction[20:16];
assign rd = instruction[15:11];
assign funct = instruction[5:0];
assign addressop = instruction[15:0];

reg [7:0] Control;

assign RegDst = Control[7];
assign RegWrite = Control[6];
assign ALUSrc = Control[5];
assign MemWrite = Control[4];
assign MemtoReg = Control[3];
assign Branch = Control[2];
assign ALUOp = Control[1:0];

initial
    Control = 7'd0;

always @(*)
    casex(Op)
        32'd0 : Control = 8'b11000010; // R-TYPE

        32'd35 : Control = 8'b01101000; // LW

        32'd43 : Control = 8'bx011x000; // SW

        32'd4 : Control = 8'bx000x101; // BEQ

        default : Control = 8'b00000000; // NOP  
    endcase

endmodule
```

Instruction Memory

```
module instruction_memory(instruction, address);

output reg [31:0] instruction;
input [31:0] address;

reg [31:0] prog [40:0];

initial
begin
    prog[0] <= 32'b000000_00000_00001_00101_00000000000;
    prog[4] <= 32'b000000_00000_00001_00101_00000000000;
    prog[8] <= 32'b000000_00000_00000_00110_00000000000;
    prog[12] <= 32'b000000_00101_00110_00110_00000000000;
    prog[16] <= 32'b000000_00101_00100_00101_00000000010;
    prog[20] <= 32'b000000_00100_00101_00111_00000001010;
    prog[24] <= 32'b000100_00111_00100_11111_11111111100; 
    prog[28] <= 32'b000000_00101_00100_00101_00000000010;
    prog[32] <= 32'b000000_00101_00100_00111_00000001010;       

    prog[36] <= 32'b000000_00100_00110_00110_00000000000;
    prog[40] <= 32'b000000_00100_00110_00110_00000000000;
end

always @(address)
    instruction = prog[address];

endmodule
```

Sign Extend

```
module sign_extend(sign_extended_address, instruction_addr);

output reg [31:0] sign_extended_address;
input [15:0] instruction_addr;

always @(*)
begin
    sign_extended_address[15:0] = instruction_addr;
    if(instruction_addr[15]==1'b1)
        sign_extended_address[31:16] = 16'b1111_1111_1111_1111;
    else
        sign_extended_address[31:16] = 16'b0000_0000_0000_0000;
end


endmodule
```

ALU Control Unit

```
module ALU_control(ALU_control_vector, ALUOp, funct);

output reg [3:0] ALU_control_vector;
input [1:0] ALUOp;
input [5:0] funct;

initial
    ALU_control_vector = 4'b0000;

always @(*)
begin
    case(ALUOp[1])
        1'b0 :  case(ALUOp[0])
                1'b0 : ALU_control_vector = 4'b0010; // ADD for LW, SW

                1'b1 : ALU_control_vector = 4'b0110; // SUB for BEQ
            endcase

        1'b1 :  case(funct[3:0])
                4'b0000 : ALU_control_vector = 4'b0010; // ADD

                4'b0100 : ALU_control_vector = 4'b0000; // AND

                4'b0101 : ALU_control_vector = 4'b0001; // OR

                4'b0010 : ALU_control_vector = 4'b0110; // SUB

                4'b1010 : ALU_control_vector = 4'b0111; // SLT

                default : ALU_control_vector = 4'b0010; // ADD (doesn't matter)
            endcase
    endcase
end

endmodule
```

ALU

```
module ALU(ALU_result, zero, operand1, operand2, ALU_control_vector);

output reg [31:0] ALU_result;
output reg zero;
input [31:0] operand1, operand2;
input [3:0] ALU_control_vector;

initial
begin
    ALU_result = 32'd0;
    zero = 0;
end

always @(*)
begin
    case(ALU_control_vector)
        4'b0000 : ALU_result = operand1 & operand2;

        4'b0001 : ALU_result = operand1 | operand2;

        4'b0010 : ALU_result = operand1 + operand2;

        4'b0110 : ALU_result = operand1 - operand2;

        4'b0111 : ALU_result = (operand1 < operand2) ? 32'd1 : 32'd0;
    endcase
    if (ALU_result == 0)
        zero = 1'b1;
    else
        zero = 1'b0;
end

endmodule
```

Register File

```
module register_file(operand1, reg_file_output2, rs, rt, write_register, write_data, RegWrite,
         register1, register4, register5, register6, register7);

output reg [31:0] operand1, reg_file_output2;
output [31:0] register0, register1, register4, register5, register6, register7;
input [31:0] write_data;
input [4:0] rs, rt, write_register;
input RegWrite;

reg [31:0] registers [31:1];  // Register 0 reserved for "0"

assign register1 = registers[1];
assign register4 = registers[4];
assign register5 = registers[5];
assign register6 = registers[6];
assign register7 = registers[7];

initial
begin
    registers[1] = 10;
    registers[4] = 1;
    registers[5] = 0;
    registers[6] = 0;
    registers[7] = 0;
    operand1 = 0;
    reg_file_output2 = 0;
end

always @(*)
begin
    operand1 = (rs == 0) ? 32'd0 : registers[rs];
    reg_file_output2 = (rt == 0) ? 32'd0 : registers[rt];
    if(RegWrite)
        registers[write_register] = write_data;
end

endmodule
```

Program Counter

```
module program_counter(next_address, address, clock, reset);

output [31:0]  next_address;
input [31:0] address;
input clock, reset;

reg [31:0] pc_next;

assign next_address = pc_next;


always @(posedge clock, posedge reset)
begin
if(reset)
    pc_next = 32'd0;
else
    pc_next = address;
end

endmodule
```

Branch Adder

```
module branch_adder(branch_address, shifted_addr_instruction, incremented_PC_addr);

output [31:0] branch_address;
input [31:0] shifted_addr_instruction, incremented_PC_addr;

assign branch_address = shifted_addr_instruction + incremented_PC_addr;

endmodule
```

Mux 1

```
module mux_2to1(out, select, a, b);

output reg [31:0] out;
input select;
input [31:0] a, b;

initial
    out = 0;

always @(*)
begin
    if(select)
        out = b;
    else
        out = a;
end

endmodule
```

Mux 2

```
module mux_2to1_5bit(out, select, a, b);

output reg [4:0] out;
input select;
input [4:0] a, b;

initial
    out = 0;

always @(*)
begin
    if(select)
        out = b;
    else
        out = a;
end

endmodule
```

PC Incrementer

```
module PC_increment(incremented_PC_address, current_address);

output [31:0] incremented_PC_address;
input [31:0] current_address;

assign incremented_PC_address = current_address + 4; 

endmodule
```

Branch/Zero AND

```
module branch_and(BEQ, branch, zero);

output BEQ;
input branch, zero;

and(BEQ, branch, zero);

endmodule
```

Left Shift Address

```
module shift_left2(shifted_address, sign_extended_address);

output [31:0] shifted_address;
input [31:0] sign_extended_address;

assign shifted_address = sign_extended_address << 2;

endmodule
```

Data Memory

```
module data_memory(data_mem_read_data, data_mem_write_data, ALU_result, MemWrite);

output reg [31:0] data_mem_read_data;
input [31:0] ALU_result, data_mem_write_data;
input MemWrite;

wire MemRead = ~MemWrite;

reg [31:0] data_registers [255:0];

initial
    data_mem_read_data = 0;

always @(ALU_result, data_mem_write_data)
begin
    if(MemWrite)
        data_registers[ALU_result] = data_mem_write_data;
    if(MemRead)
        data_mem_read_data = data_registers[ALU_result];
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain, in words, how you believe branching is supposed to work in your design.  Particularly include how you have implemented the MIPS branch delay slot.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I have edited to include an explanation of how I expect branching to work. I should have mentioned that this is supposed to be a single-cycle processor. It's my understanding that I don't need to worry about branch delay in this case, but maybe I'm wrong? As I say, I'm quite new to this so I don't actually know what a branch delay slot is, just that it seems to be mentioned as being necessary for a pipelined processor.

Comment: I don't know where your bug is, but I have some general verilog tips for you. 1. Never use position based on port lists. Always use name based. You'll end up adding more ports and messing everything up. 2. You have way more modules than you need. A bunch of your modules just so one line of combinational logic, so do it in line. 3. You can simplify a lot of logic. You have a case statement checking if a signal is all 0 or not, and assigning one output to that. You could just as easily do "assign foo = (bar!=0);".

Comment: And if you simulation is stalling, there's a combinational loop somewhere. Equivalent of a = ~a;.

Comment: "MIPS" in combination with "single cycle branch" is an *oxymoron*.  At the very least, by failing to implement a branch delay slot, you've broken binary compatibility.  Even if your design ultimately works, you'll be confined to hand assembly, as you won't be able to use compilers which assume this.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I have no intention to use the design for anything other than as an educational tool. Once I have this working, I can start looking at pipelining, implementing the rest of the MIPS instruction set, branch delay, adding caches, etc. As I say, I'm fairly new to this so I'm not even looking beyond hand assembly for the time being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any sequential always block, you must use non blocking assignment (the less than/equal sign, <=). If it's not the cause of this problem, it will cause one layer for sure.

Comment: It works! Looks like changing to non blocking assignments and also making the register file outputs wires and continuously assigning from the selected registers fixed the problem. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

The rule is simply:
If one process writes to a variable synchronized to an event, and another process reads the *same* variable synchronized to the *same* event, you need to write using an NBA ensuring that the reading process uses the old value of the variable. 
If instead you use a blocking assignment in this situation, there's a race condition between getting the new or old value of the variable because the execution ordering between the reading and writing processes is indeterminate.

By "event" I mean an edge of a clock or enable. And by "same" I mean the identical or some combinational expression of the same signal.